# SwiftUI - NavigationLink(value: ) and navigationDestination not working

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swift-data, ios17

I have a SwiftData model called `Diem` with variables `id`, `name`, and `date`. I want to navigate from HomeView to DiemDetail, but the NavigationLink does not work. Xcode shows no errors.

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    @Query(sort: \Diem.date) 
    private var diems: [Diem]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            DiemsGrid()
                .navigationDestination(for: Diem.ID.self) { diemID in
                    if let diem = diems.first(where: { $0.id == diemID }) {
                        DiemDetail(diem: diem)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct DiemsGrid: View {
    @Query(sort: \Diem.date) var diems: [Diem]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: layout, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(diems) { diem in
                    DiemGridItem(diem: diem)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct DiemGridItem: View {
    var diem: Diem
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: diem.id) {
            // View code
        }
    }
}
```

And DiemDetail

```swift
struct DiemDetail: View {
    var diem: Diem

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack() {
                // views
            }
            .toolbar {
                // views
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Diem` model is all good. I do have a `.sheet` in DiemDetail and HomeView but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Try after removing `NavigationStack` from the `DiemDetail` view because parent view has NavigationStack already. It works for me.

Comment: @Asad Worked like magic. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're having duplicate `NavigationStack` on both `HomeView` and `DiemDetail`. DiemDetail also has navigation from its parent, which is HomeView. Unless you remove it, it will not work, because the first time you have pushed to `DiemDetail`, navigation will be replaced with the nested one, which does not handle `.navigationDestination` anymore.

Secondly, `NavigationLink` in `DiemGridItem` takes the correct type, which is mapped with `.navigationDestination` from its ancestor. However, you did not provide its appearance, that's why you didn't see any tappable links.

So combine those things:

```swift
struct DiemGridItem: View {
    var diem: Diem
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: diem.id) {
            Text(diem.id.uuidString)
        }
    }
}

struct DiemDetail: View {
    var diem: Diem

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
        }
        .toolbar {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```